# How to Increment a Speed Variable Over Time While a Key is Pressed?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in pygame. I have a character who's position is altered like so (There are 3 others for L, R, and D as well):

```
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 10
```

This moves the character 10 pixels every 60ms. I would like to write a function that increments the speed the longer the key is pressed and then resets the speed after the key is released. I have tried this:

```
def speed(velocity):
velocity *= 2
return velocity

if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    y -= speed(10)
```

This only increases the parameter by 2 but does not increment it the longer the key is pressed, and I could not figure out how to reset the variable to its initial state after releasing the key.
How would I implement this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little example of a real-time falling sprite.  Pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> decreases the speed, and <kbd>Down</kbd> increases it.  I probably over-complicated the example, but if one pushes <kbd>Up</kbd> enough times, the flower-pot will fall up.

I've implemented this as an object that inherits from the PyGame [sprite class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).  One of the nice things using an object brings, is being able to keep all the attributes of the item (like, location, bitmap, speed, etc.) *inside* the object. This means your program isn't littered with global variables for *this* and *that*. The PyGame sprite also brings with it lots of useful and elegant functionality.  Sure it's a little bit of extra work at the beginning, but later on, programming progress will be much smoother and *easier*.  (If you don't want to use objects, at least put everything into a python dictionary or suchlike to keep it all together `{"x":0, "y":0, "speed":3}` etc.)

Anyway... the important part of the code is `FallingSprite.update()`.  This takes the time between the last call to `update()` and `now`, using it to calculate how many pixels the object should move, given its speed.  The code uses a simple constant-velocity calculation, not a proper falling-under-gravity calculation, but the formula could be just swapped in.  The difference is calculated, then applied to the `x` & `y` co-ordinates of the sprite's `rect` (which sets the position on-screen).  If the object falls of the bottom of the screen (or the top) it "wraps" around to start again.

```
import pygame
import time
import sys

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
# background colour
SKY_BLUE      = (161, 255, 254)


class FallingSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A falling flower-pot sprite.  Falls at a given velocity in real-time """
    def __init__( self ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = pygame.image.load("flower_pot.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, -50 )
        self.fall_speed  = 150 # pixels / second
        self.image_height= self.image.get_rect().height
        self.last_update = int( time.time() * 1000.0 )

    def update( self ):
        # There should have been movement since the last update
        # calculate the new position
        time_now    = int( time.time() * 1000.0 )
        time_change = time_now - self.last_update             # How long since last update?
        # If we're moving, and time has passed
        if ( self.fall_speed != 0 and time_change > 0 ):
            distance_moved   = time_change * abs( self.fall_speed ) / 1000
            now_x, now_y     = self.rect.center               # Where am I, right now
            # Fall down (or up)
            if ( self.fall_speed > 0 ):
                updated_y = now_y + distance_moved
            else:
                updated_y = now_y - distance_moved
            # Did we fall off the bottom of the screen?
            if ( updated_y > WINDOW_HEIGHT + self.image_height ):
                updated_y = -self.image.get_rect().height     # move to just above top of screen
            # ... or off the top?
            elif ( updated_y < 0 - self.image_height ):
                updated_y = WINDOW_HEIGHT + self.image_height # move to just below screen
            # Reposition the sprite
            self.rect.center = ( now_x, updated_y )
        self.last_update = time_now

    def adjustSpeed( self, amount ):
        self.fall_speed += amount

    def stop( self ):
        self.fall_speed  = 0



### MAIN
pygame.init()
WINDOW    = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Flowerpot")

# Add some sprites
FALLERS   = pygame.sprite.Group()   # a group, for a single sprite
flower_pot_sprite = FallingSprite()
FALLERS.add( flower_pot_sprite )


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        flower_pot_sprite.adjustSpeed( -5 ) 
        print( "slower... ", end='' )
        sys.stdout.flush()

    elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        flower_pot_sprite.adjustSpeed( 5 )  
        print( "faster! ", end='' )
        sys.stdout.flush()


    # Move the flower-pot, did it hit anything?
    FALLERS.update() # re-position the flower-pot

    # Re-draw the screen
    WINDOW.fill( SKY_BLUE )
    FALLERS.draw( WINDOW )    # draw the flower-pot
    pygame.display.flip()
    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )

pygame.quit()
```

[image: flower_pot.png]

I realise that's technically a *cactus pot*, please don't write in.

Answer (score 1):

You've started on the correct approach, but the problem is that you're storing the speed in a local variable inside the function. This variable will be reset every time you call the function.

Instead you should store the speed somewhere else:

```
# Somewhere earlier in the program, eg. before your main loop
# Store the initial speed in a variable
base_speed = 10
# Initialise current speed to initial speed
speed = base_speed
```

Then in your check for whether the key is pressed, you could do something like this:

```
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    y -= speed
    # Increase speed for the next round
    speed *= 2
else:
    # Did not press the key this time
    # Reset current speed to the initial speed (10, stored in the variable base_speed)
    speed = base_speed
```

The important part in this kind of a solution is

1. that `speed` is initialised before whatever loop you're doing the checking in, so that it does not get reset every time you enter the loop and
2. that it's initialised in the same function that you're using it in, so it is accessible to the function

Comment: I understand what you mean. The only issue is the use of time.sleep() now. When I try to increase the variable over time, the whole animation sleeps for the time sleep in the function, essentially inducing man-made lag. Is there a way to base it off of a clock and not have the program sleep?

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep()`, instead limit your frame rate, see [clock.tick(60)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock).